# Angular 2 app on eclipse tomcat

Tags: javascript, eclipse, tomcat, typescript, angular

I am running a java based application in tomcat server. I want to put my angular2(typescript) based single page application in the same server.

I know I can transpile (translate/compile) typescript to javascript with nodejs and put that compiled version to tomcat.

But I want to do this in eclipse/tomcat like node tsc do. Is there a way/plugin in eclipse that directly compile typescript to javascript and deploy that on tomcat?

Comment: _transpile (translate/compile) typescript to javascript with nodejs_ why with nodejs? typescript does have it's compiler.

Comment: I mean with nodejs typescript compiler i.e. *tsc* as package in npm

Comment: If I have to do development with ng2 I will go for gulp task runner.

Comment: @Akshay what is the problem you are having with tsc???

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Don't have any problem, I just don't want another server for compilation if I could